# how to prevent jquery ui default first tab to active when refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

i am using `jquery ui` as navigation for my site and inside each tab i put some links to pages which are basically loaded dynamically by ajax. every thing working fine except one problem!

> **problem**

my problem is that when i clicked other then first tab and hit refresh from my browser it takes me back to default first tab. as i said i used links inside these tabs and these links are supposed to be navigation of my site, but with this problem this is not good! for example if i click tab `two` and then click any one of links inside of it i.e `SubMenu 1.1` and its working and load contents normally but what happens when i hit browser refresh button it takes me back to tab `one` although i am still at tab `two` `SubMenu 1.1`
here is code.

```
  <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     <div id="fragment-1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.1">SubMenu 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.2">SubMenu 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.3">SubMenu 1.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.4">SubMenu 1.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.5">SubMenu 1.5</a></li>
        <ul>
     </div>
     <div id="fragment-2">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.1">SubMenu 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.2">SubMenu 2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.3">SubMenu 2.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.4">SubMenu 2.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.5">SubMenu 2.5</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="fragment-3">
       <ul>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.1">SubMenu 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.2">SubMenu 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.3">SubMenu 3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.4">SubMenu 3.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.5">SubMenu 3.5</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

also used local storage but its not working althought browser supported `firefox 39` `chrome 43` and `Ie 11`

```
if(window.localStorage!==undefined){
   var selected=0;
   if(localStorage.currentTab){
      selected=Number(localStorage.currentTab)
   }else{
      localStorage.currentTab=0;
   }

   $("#tabs").tabs({ 
      selected: selected,
      select: function(event, ui) {
      localStorage.currentTab=ui.index
   }
   });//Do something
 }else{
      alert('Your browser is outdated therefore not supported local stroage!');
 }
```

also used this from official site of `jquery ui` with different values but didn't work as i want.

```
  $( ".selector" ).tabs({
    active: 1
  });
```

help will be really appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `active` property instead of `selected`

And `activate` instead of `selected` handler.

Also `ui.index` is undefined as that property is not available on the `ui` object.

Instead use  `$(ui.newTab[0]).index()` - The jQuery object gives you the current `li` and you can get the index of it.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ 
   active: selected,
   activate: function(event, ui) {
     localStorage.currentTab = $(ui.newTab[0]).index()
   }
});
```

Always use the developer tools to debug or check for any errors. That makes life easier.

**[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zc626ykk/)**

Comment: thanks for support i will check in a minute the tell you what happens hope this works.

Comment: thanks for ans it works, but i have one more problem! can i use a page link inside my main tabs `one` `two` and `three` so when click on them also load default contents. since main tabs are linked with `href` to sublinks `id` and i can't figure out how to do?

Comment: Can you provide an example ??

Comment: for example i wanted to put url `#browse.php` in main tab `one` where as you see in the above code he has already a url that is linked to its subtabs by id and i want to put `#browse.php` instead of  `#fragment-1`. i tried to putting it there but didn't work. or any other way of linking parent tab to child tabs so url becomes free so i able to put url of my desire there.

Comment: yes! but it only shows subtabs and not loads the page. as i said earlier the reason why i wanted to put `browse.php` instead of `##fragment-1` because i suppose to load that page when click on these tabs as well as shows subtabs. did you understand what i am trying to do?

Comment: i don't think that can be directly. One way of doing this is using the `activate` event take care of that and based on the tab index make a ajax call and display the `browser.php` page.

Comment: sorry but i don't understood what are you talking about that! can you plz give me an example please!

Comment: Something in these lines `activate: function (event, ui) {
    var currentTab = $(ui.newTab[0]).index();
    if (currentTab === 0) {
        // Load browse1
        $(this).load('browse1.php');
    } else {
      // some other page
    }
}`

Comment: thanks for the `fiddle` now it loads the page but didn't update the url in the browser address bar. i have an idea instead of doing this can i put `browse.php` in one of subtab and it should open that subtab as default when it get clicked.